# Calling node express server API from Vue application running in a different port

Tags: node.js, express, webpack, vuejs2, vue-resource

I recently started learning vue.js and currently using vue.js with [vue-simple-webpack](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack-simple) template , express and mongo to develop a simple application . I am using localhost to develop and test the application.

application front-end runs in port **8080** and the server is running in a different port **(3000)**

Here is my `server.js` where i have a simple api to get data from my `localdb`

```
const express = require('express');
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const mongodb = require('mongodb');
const bodyParser= require('body-parser');
const app = express();
var db;

var URL='mongodb://localhost:27017/'+'mydb';
console.log(URL);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))
app.use(bodyParser.json())

MongoClient.connect(URL, (err, database) => {
  if (err) 
    return console.log(err);
  db = database;
  app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('listening on 3000');
  })
})

app.get('/products', (req, res) => {
    db.collection('products').find().toArray(function(err, results) {
    console.log(results)
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.send(JSON.stringify(results));
    })
})
```

tested the server.js , it works . see below screenshot.

[image]

Vue application is running in `http://localhost:8080/` using the webpack template's default configuration. i am trying to call the `/products` api end from the vue.js file using $http get as follows...

```
export default {
  name: 'Products',
  methods: {
        get: function() {
            // GET request
            this.$http({
                url: '/products',
                method: 'GET'
            }).then(function(response) {
                console.log('ok');
            }, function(response) {
                console.log('failed');
            });
        }
    }
}
```

But i get the following error in the browser console.

[image]

As you can see , even though i am using the port `3000` in `server.js` , when i try access the `/products` api end , it actually goes through port `8080`. Therefore it throws a **404** http error .

My question is how i can access the API end from within the front-end which runs in a different port. Is that even possible ?

Can i use [API Proxying](http://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/proxy.html) here . If so , can somebody point me in the correct direction on how to do it since there are not much info available on the web.

Comment: `$http()` should allow you to specify the port.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use proxy configuration provided by webpack.

Docs: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-proxy

snippet config:

```
proxy: {
  "/products": "http://localhost:3000/products"
}
```

A better practice would be forwarding /api/* requests to http://host:port/api/* urls.

Comment: I added the proxy in the webpack web config . Also changed server urls to /api/* pattern like you suggested . But the issue is still there when i try to access the /api/products . the $http.get method tries to access the /api/products from within the localhost:8080 port . therefore i am getting the 404 error

Comment: Please refer this issue i have raised in my code github code repo. https://github.com/mal90/adApp/issues/3

Comment: You can add following config. I just checked out the code and tested. It worked fine. :)

 proxy: {
  "/api/": {
   target: "http://localhost:3000/",
   secure: false
 }
    }

Comment: Correct . that works . In my early solution with proxy , i made a mistake . Thank you @Saurabh

Comment: This is brilliant, and by far the most simple solution to this whole CORS problem.